# Newtonsoft deserializing string to double issue

Tags: json.net

This is relevant line of code:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();     
object result = serializer.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(val)), type);
```

val is sting, type is double

Scenario:

1. val "12.35318" is deserialized to res 12.35318 double, and that is ok
2. val "12.73407" is deserialized to res 12.734070000000001!

My question is:

- why is this 2. case happening?
- is there way to use Newtonsoft lib. and get "12.73407" serialized to exactly 12.73407 double?

Thank you

Comment: That's just the nature of floating point numbers.  Here's some [relevant reading](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: In floating-point numbers, there are lots of concrete real (even rational) numbers which cannot be exactly represented. Probably this is the case here too, but just a tip.

Comment: If precise representation is important, I suggest using the `decimal` type.

Comment: More relevant reading, a little more digestible: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)